# Perform Multi-Dimension Scaling (MDS) for clustered categorical data in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, categorical-data, multi-dimensional-scaling

I am currently working on clustering categorical attributes that come from a bank marketing dataset from Kaggle. I have created the three clusters with kmodes:

Output: [cluster_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6aOv.jpg)

Now I want to visualize each row of a cluster as a projection or point so that I get some kind of image:

[Desired visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reWO7.png)

I am having a hard time with this. I don't get a Euclidean distance with categorized data, right? That makes no sense. Is there then no possibility to create this desired visualization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to visualize clusters is to use PCA.
You can use PCA to reduce the multi-dimensional data into 2 dimensions so that you can plot and hopefully understand the data better.
To use it see the following code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
```

where x is the fitted and transformed data on your cluster.
Now u can easily visualize your clustered data since it's 2 dimensional.